# Any options for XSLT code library

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have about 40 XSLT files and was searching for a convenient ways to package and reuse components.

Comment: It sounds as if you are looking for XSLT 3.0 packages https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#packages.

Comment: The XSL Wg would greatly value your feedback on the details of the XSLT 3 spec. Nearly all the XSLT packaging features are implemented in Saxon 9.7, though with some restrictions and somewhat limited testing.